# Force the value of input (Search As You Type) in the list?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

(Asp.net core 3.1, Blazor server side)

I'm building a dropdown input with suggestions loaded dynamically by the typing value in the input box. How to force the value of `<input>` in the list `suggestions`? (like the `<select>`)

```
<datalist id="suggestions">
    @foreach (var b in filteredList)
    {
        <option value="@b.Value">@b.Text</option>
    }
</datalist>
<input autoComplete="on" list="suggestions" value="@theValueEntered"
               @oninput="OnInputChanged"
               @onfocus='() => OnInputChanged(new ChangeEventArgs { Value = "" })'/>

@code {
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
    private string theValueEntered;
    private IEnumerable<Data> filteredList;

    private Task OnInputChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        theValueEntered = e.Value as string;
        cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
        cancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;

        awaitTask.Delay(250, token);
        filteredList = await dbContext.Data // Millions rows
                            .Where(x => x.Name.StartWith(theValueEntered)
                            .Take(25)
                            .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you want? I don't think I understand where you want to add data.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to the filtered list

```
filteredList.Add(theValueEntered);
```

or add it to the front

```
filteredList.Insert(0, theValueEntered);
```